# Building a basic funnel using Google Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I noticed that there are a lot of users of Google Analytics with Google BigQuery but the documentation is quite limited.  Is it possible to help generate a simple funnel that shows Users who visited /pageA then /pageB and then /pageC

I have seen lots of different approaches - and I am not clear what the "correct" way is to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate hits of users first with array_concat_agg() and then do your calculations based on the new user scoped table. It highly depends on your chosen time frame of course.

Here for instance with dummy data from Google:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH arrAgg AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid,
    -- concatenate arrays over multiple sessions
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(hits ORDER BY visitstarttime ASC) userHits
  FROM
    `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
  GROUP BY 1
)
, journey AS (
  SELECT 
    fullvisitorId,
    -- get a proper running index with combination of unnest and offset of aggregated hits array
    ARRAY( (SELECT AS STRUCT index+1 as hitNumber, page FROM UNNEST(userHits) WITH OFFSET AS index)) as hits
  FROM arrAgg
)

SELECT * FROM journey
```

When you run this you can see the new "raw material". In the first step I concatenate the hits, in the second step I make a proper index for the pages and put eerything back into a "hits" array.

You can build your user journey using cross joins and comparing steps and sequence of the page:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH arrAgg AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid,
    SUM(totals.visits) sessions,
    -- concatenate arrays over multiple sessions
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(hits ORDER BY visitstarttime ASC) userHits
  FROM
    `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
  GROUP BY 1
)
, journey AS (
  SELECT 
    fullvisitorId,
    sessions,
    -- get a proper running index with combination of unnest and offset of aggregated hits array
    ARRAY( (SELECT AS STRUCT index+1 as hitNumber, page FROM UNNEST(userHits) WITH OFFSET AS index WHERE type='PAGE')) as hits
  FROM arrAgg
)
-- funnel: homepage: /, login: /login.html, basket: /basket.html, confirm: /confirm.html
SELECT 
  SUM(sessions) allSessions,
  COUNT(1) allUsers,
  -- check if any page was home page
  SUM( (SELECT IF( LOGICAL_OR(page.pagePath='/'), 1, 0) FROM j.hits) ) step1_home,
  -- cross join hits array with itself: combination of all pages with all pages: any of those combinations our two pages? came home before login?: if yes for any given amount add up 1
  SUM( (SELECT IF( LOGICAL_OR(a.page.pagePath='/' AND b.page.pagePath='/login.html' AND a.hitNumber < b.hitNumber) ,1, 0 ) FROM j.hits a CROSS JOIN j.hits b) ) step2_login,
  -- extend cross join principle to a third page
  SUM( (SELECT IF( LOGICAL_OR(
      a.page.pagePath='/' AND b.page.pagePath='/login.html' AND c.page.pagePath='/basket.html' AND
      a.hitNumber < b.hitNumber AND b.hitNumber < c.hitNumber 
      ) ,1, 0 ) FROM j.hits a CROSS JOIN j.hits b CROSS JOIN j.hits c) ) step3_basket,
  -- extend cross join principle to a fourth page
  SUM( (SELECT IF( LOGICAL_OR(
      a.page.pagePath='/' AND b.page.pagePath='/login.html' AND c.page.pagePath='/basket.html' AND d.page.pagePath='/confirm.html' AND
      a.hitNumber < b.hitNumber AND b.hitNumber < c.hitNumber AND c.hitNumber < d.hitNumber
      ) ,1, 0 ) FROM j.hits a CROSS JOIN j.hits b CROSS JOIN j.hits c CROSS JOIN j.hits d) ) step4_confirm
FROM journey j
```

Since everything operates with subqueries on arrays it should scale quite well, because of parallelization.
Please test it before using it - I didn't ;) But it should point in the right direction.

Comment: Looks awesome Martin - thanks. I will try understand it a bit more and test it out.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: sorry -been slow, I found a simpler way to do it- butI want to explore your solution to see if its better ( more accurate) Just its a lot more code to understand

Comment: @MobileBloke Could you post the simpler solution as an answer, please? Just to make it available for everyone.

Comment: 100% will do it - if its better.  I have had to jump on another issue so I have marked this correct.

Comment: I was very curious to try this, but the query has been running for more than 3 minutes, although the amount processed is only 192MB. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Check here: https://online-behavior.com/analytics/funnel-analysis

Alternatively, if you want to do it by hand:

1. Select all sessions landing on start page (record smallest hit number)
2. LEFT JOIN with select all sessions on next page where hit number is greater than hit number from start page (match session IDs)
3. Repeat step 2 until the funnel is complete
4. Count all sessions grouped by page name to aggregate

Comment: yes - all those seem to focus on sessions based funnels - not really "user" based funnels

Comment: You can easily count by visitorid or a custom user definition instead.