# GA Funnel Analysis in Big Query - "Correct" Session Counts

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Thank you for stopping by! I would be grateful to (re)create the ultimate GA Session Funnel in Big Query. The focus is on the funnel per session, with certain, but not necessarily sequentially visited pages during one session.

[image: Desired result from query]

The solution should count sessions as `COUNT( DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)))`.

Further, the funnel should be of the form that every funnel step can only be reached if the previous step has been completed within a session (e.g. the fourth step should only be counted if steps 1 - 3 have been visited during the session). However, the steps do not need to be performed consecutively

That is, unfortunately, why [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332898/recreate-ga-funnel-on-bigquery), which I like a lot,  would not work for me. It returns numbers for visits of `totals.visits`. Also, I need to use `REGXP_CONTAINS` for the pages, as I do not have events (or custom dimensions) on my pages for the funnel steps. For the original query (for every respective step)

```
SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventAction = 'landing_page' LIMIT 1)) Landing_Page
```

I tried:

```
COUNT( DISTINCT( SELECT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) FROM UNNEST(GA.hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r”myfunnelpage”)
```

However, my funnel step visits are actually more than my total “sessions” as per `COUNT( DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))) AS overday_sessions`.

Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249941/building-a-basic-funnel-using-google-big-query) looks at user sessions (I am incredibly impressed, also absolutely intimidated, props to @Martin) 
Allegedly, there is a [website](https://online-behavior.com/analytics/funnel-analysis) that ought to have it all is down when I wrote this #StuffGettingLostOnline

My approach would look something like this. But it returns only sessions with single page views, not sequential ones:

```
SELECT
  date,       
  COUNT( DISTINCT( SELECT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) FROM UNNEST(GA.hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r"productoverviewpage") LIMIT 1)) AS product_overview_s1,

  COUNT( DISTINCT( SELECT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) FROM UNNEST(GA.hits) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(GA.hitS) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r"productoverviewregex")) AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, cartoverviewregex") LIMIT 1)) AS cart_overview_s2

FROM 
 data as GA,
 UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE hits.type = "PAGE"
AND 
 TRUE IN UNNEST(
  [REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r"productoverviewpage"),
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r"cartoverviewregex""]
 )
```

Any ideas? Anyone able to recreate the ultimate big query funnel using the “correct” session count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline subqueries to check for the individual steps of the funnel:

```
WITH
  sessions AS (
  SELECT
    (
    SELECT
      hits
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits) hits
    WHERE
      hits.page.pagePath = "/"
    ) first_step,
    (
    SELECT
      hits
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits) hits
    WHERE
      hits.page.pagePath = "/basket"
    ) second_step
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`)
SELECT
  COUNT(first_step) sessions_step_one,
  COUNTIF(first_step.hitNumber < second_step.hitNumber) sessions_step_two
FROM
  sessions
```

Comment: this query gives the following error `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`- not sure why it has been voted as correct